# API Endpoint Error During Integration Tests but Not Normal Startup

Tags: c#, api, integration-testing

I'm working on integration tests for my api that works perfectly fine when using a normal startup and launch profile, but when I run it on my integration test, I get an `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: A. Path '', line 0, position 0.` error. This looks like it's having trouble with the json at the endpoint, but I can't imagine why. Again, it works just fine during normal operation. Here's a few snippets that Might be applicable. Happy to provide more if needed.

**test**

```cs
public class GetValueToReplaceIntegrationTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        public GetValueToReplaceIntegrationTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;
        [Fact]
        public async Task GetValueToReplaces_ReturnsSuccessCodeAndResourceWithAccurateFields()
        {
            var fakeValueToReplaceOne = new FakeValueToReplace { }.Generate();
            var fakeValueToReplaceTwo = new FakeValueToReplace { }.Generate();

            var appFactory = _factory;
            using (var scope = appFactory.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ValueToReplaceDbContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                context.ValueToReplaces.RemoveRange(context.ValueToReplaces);
                context.ValueToReplaces.AddRange(fakeValueToReplaceOne, fakeValueToReplaceTwo);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            var client = appFactory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            });

            var result = await client.GetAsync($"api/v1/ValueToReplaceLowers")
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            var responseContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ValueToReplaceDto>>(responseContent);

            // Assert
            result.StatusCode.Should().Be(200);
            response.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(fakeValueToReplaceOne);
            response.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(fakeValueToReplaceTwo);
        }
    }
```

**fixture**

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Remove the app's ValueToReplaceDbContext registration.
                var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    d => d.ServiceType ==
                        typeof(DbContextOptions<ValueToReplaceDbContext>));

                if (descriptor != null)
                {
                    services.Remove(descriptor);
                }

                // Add ValueToReplaceDbContext using an in-memory database for testing.
                services.AddDbContext<ValueToReplaceDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestingDb");
                });

                // Build the service provider.
                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database
                using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ValueToReplaceDbContext>();

                    // Ensure the database is created.
                    db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                    try
                    {
                        db.RemoveRange(db.ValueToReplaces);
                        // Seed the database with test data.
                        //Utilities.InitializeDbForTests(db);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**startup**

```cs
namespace Foundation.Api
{
    using AutoBogus;
    using Autofac;
    using AutoMapper;
    using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
    using Foundation.Api.Data;
    using Foundation.Api.Data.Entities;
    using Foundation.Api.Services;
    using MediatR;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Sieve.Services;
    using System;

    public class Startup
    {
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "MyCorsPolicy";

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddResponseCompression();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            });

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddScoped<SieveProcessor>();

            services.AddScoped<IValueToReplaceRepository, ValueToReplaceRepository>();

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>())
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(
                op =>
                {
                    op.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                    op.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
                });

            services.AddDbContext<ValueToReplaceDbContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("ValueToReplaceDb"));

            services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));

            //services.AddControllers()

            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            });
        }

        // https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html
        public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            using (var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ValueToReplaceDbContext>())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                // auto generate some fake data. added rules to accomodate placeholder validation rules
                context.ValueToReplaces.Add(new AutoFaker<ValueToReplace>()
                    .RuleFor(fake => fake.ValueToReplaceDateField1, fake => fake.Date.Past())
                    .RuleFor(fake => fake.ValueToReplaceIntField1, fake => fake.Random.Number()));
                context.ValueToReplaces.Add(new AutoFaker<ValueToReplace>()
                    .RuleFor(fake => fake.ValueToReplaceDateField1, fake => fake.Date.Past())
                    .RuleFor(fake => fake.ValueToReplaceIntField1, fake => fake.Random.Number()));
                context.ValueToReplaces.Add(new AutoFaker<ValueToReplace>()
                    .RuleFor(fake => fake.ValueToReplaceDateField1, fake => fake.Date.Past())
                    .RuleFor(fake => fake.ValueToReplaceIntField1, fake => fake.Random.Number()));

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            app.UseResponseCompression();

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**endpoint**

```cs
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/v1/ValueToReplaceLowers")]
    public class ValueToReplacesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public ValueToReplacesController(IMediator mediator)
        {
            _mediator = mediator ??
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mediator));
        }

        [HttpGet("{valueToReplaceId}", Name = "GetValueToReplace")]
        public IActionResult GetValueToReplace(int valueToReplaceId)
        {
            var query = new GetValueToReplaceQuery(valueToReplaceId);
            var result = _mediator.Send(query);

            return result.Result != null ? (IActionResult) Ok(result.Result) : NotFound();
        }
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you actually looked at the json that is being returned?  I suspect it starts `<html`, i.e. it's returning a default web page, probably a 404 page.

Comment: Thanks, I should have clarified. It's not actually getting anything back (which makes sense for the json parse failing). I added an image of the breakpoint to my post. So then, the question is, why is it throwing a 500 error when making the request in my integaration test and not in my normal startup?